# Pusher library for Node.js or PHP which can subscribe to channels?

Tags: php, node.js, pusher

I'am trying to build server-side client for Pusher. Client shoud be able to subscribe to channels and react to events... After getting info from DB etc it shoud send info to another clients (Javascript, Arduino).

Problem is I cant find any server side library which will be able subscribing to Pusher channel and binding to events...

Is something like this already written? Do you have some tips?

Answer (score 3):

here - https://github.com/abhishiv/pusher-server

pusher client for node.js

Answer (score 1):

Since an answer hasn't been chosen I will answer with what I used in May 2014:  [Pusher Node.js Client](https://github.com/dirkbonhomme/pusher-client-node)

This library is an open source client that allows Node.js applications to connect to the Pusher webservice. It aims to be fully compatible and up-to-date with Pusher's official JavaScript client. Github.com/dirkbonhomme

Comment: Seems that you can't trigger an event using this library? So it can only be used to subscribe to event....

Comment: @tomsoft you will need to authenticate it first.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually related to the [Pusher.com](http://pusher.com/) but you could take a look at faye for node.js. It's not actually a different service. You will have to host it, and I'm not saying it's better or worst than Pusher.

http://faye.jcoglan.com/

Node specific http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html

You can create a server in node.js. (Example from the guides)

```
var http = require('http'),
    faye = require('faye');

var bayeux = new faye.NodeAdapter({mount: '/faye', timeout: 45});
bayeux.listen(8000);
```

And client at server side node.js in a different server, so you can publish or subscribe to channels. (At the faye server there is a client already attached)

```
var client = new faye.Client('http://localhost:8000/faye');
```

And you can also use it in the browser

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:8000/faye');
</script>
```

Comment: -1 The question is asking about how to subscribe to a channel from PHP or node.js. If you can provide more information about why Faye is a better solution in this scenario then maybe your answer is justified.

Comment: As I said it can be used with node.js

Comment: But Faye can't be used with Pusher. Does Faye offer PubSub and have a similar concept to channels? Can you subscribe to data as a client within a node.js application? If you can provide more information in your answer relevant to the question then it may well be worth an upvote.

Comment: Mr. @leggetter here are the examples you asked. I just limited to copy from the guides but ok.. At least I should had pointed a link for it, so I understand why you are complaining.

Comment: Not complaining, just asking for clarification so that the answer is relevant to the question :) I think you've achieved that by demonstrating that it is an alternative solution, offers similar functionality and you can connect as a client from the server :)

Comment: Thanks for making me improve my answer. I actually just realized it was a question about a specific service. I thought he needed server and client library. Nice to meet you Phil and I will take a look at Pusher! I never stumbled on it.